# My datas are in 3 columns in Dataframe in code window but in 1 column when export to csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 3 files (txt or csv) that each contain 1 column with "Value" in first row and then numbers in following rows. [Image of my file1 when open with excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7x54X.png). I am trying to create a .csv file that have data of file 1 in column 1, file 2 in column 2 and file 3 in column 3.

The code I have at the moment create a dataframe with exactly what I want, 3 columns with the data of my 3 files in each. But when I export to a .csv file, all I manage to do was to have all in 1 column.
[My dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hh3Q0.png)

Sometime row1 of col1 followed by row1 of col2, row1 col3 and then row2 col1, row2 col2 and so on (combined1). [Image of combined1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46rwr.png).
Sometime all the rows of col1, followed by all rows of col2 followed by all rows of col3(combined3).[Image of combined3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cczS.png).
It also seem to get index number somehow?

I tried to create a dataframe with made up data separated by comas thinking this could be the problem but it didn't fix it. I also tried removing "Value" to keep only numbers but it didn't fix it.

I would really appreciate your help as I am very lost right now. Also, I do realise that my code is not the prettiest but I am a very beginner... if you have more "elegant" ways to code it, I would be happy to learn!

If you need more information, I have my code (CICg_03) and my test folder/files on Github.

```
file_list = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format('csv'))]
#print(file_list)

filename1 = file_list[0]
filename2 = file_list[1]
filename3 = file_list[2]

with open(filename1) as f1:
    datalist1 = f1.readlines()

with open(filename2) as f2:
    datalist2 = f2.readlines()

with open(filename3) as f3:
    datalist3 = f3.readlines()

print(datalist1)
print(datalist2)
print(datalist3)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    filename1: datalist1,
    filename2: datalist2,
    filename3: datalist3
})
print(df1)

df1.to_csv ('combined1.csv', sep='\n')
df3 = df1.transpose()
df3.to_csv ('combined3.csv', sep='\n')
```

Following suggestion of MDR (thank you):
I tried the "replace" idea, it didn't fix the issue ["replace" with combine1 and combine3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SQyU.png)
I tried the "sep with coma" idea, it didn't fix the issue ["sep coma" with combine1 and combine3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcbuj.png)
I tried the "no sep" idea, it didn't fix the issue ["no sep" with combine1 and combine3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azQrB.png)
I also tried the "replace" with "sep coma" and "no sep" solution but it didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `sep='\n'`?  Either remove or use `sep=','`.  Without a sample set of data it's hard to say more.

Comment: From the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/hh3Q0.png you may need `df1 = df1.replace(r'\\n',' ', regex=True)` to remove unneeded newline characters

Comment: @MDR Thank you for your suggestions, I edited my post with the try. It didn't work unfortunately. Feel free to check here to get my sample of dataset .https://github.com/Orohena/CombineIntoCsv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably don't fully understand what is required.  However, to offer something: I would suggest using pandas to read in the files.  Example:

Given different input files of:

[image]

And code to pull them into a dataframe...

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Values1.csv')

df['Value2'] = pd.read_csv('Values2.csv')

df['Value3'] = pd.read_csv('whatever.csv')

print(df)
```

[image]

You can then output to one CSV file with one extra line...

```
df.to_csv('combined.csv', index=False)
```

That looks like...

[image]

UPDATE:

If you want to rename columns, or switch ordering etc. then try adding (just before the output to CSV) the lines (edit as required)...

```
df.rename({'Value': 'You', 'Value2': 'What', 'Value3': 'Want'}, axis=1, inplace=True)

df = df.reindex(columns=['What', 'You', 'Want'])
```

Which changes the names and order to...
[image]

Comment: Note that even if the files have a `.txt` you can use read_csv.  Hence this is valid: `pd.read_csv('whatever.txt')`

Comment: Thank you so much @MDR, it works very well and it is much more elegant than what I had. So simplified! I will need to make a plot from those 3 datas later. But with this code, when I open the csv as excel, it is all in one column separated by coma. (row1 colA contain "Value, Value2, Value3". Is there a way to force it to put in colA, colB, colC ? I plan to code it as well (if I can) and I guess in that case I will need only the DataFrame. But if I need to do by hand, it would be convenient to have it properly as Excel. Anyway, it is already a massive help ! Thank you again !

Comment: @Orohena I've added an UPDATE section to the answer if that helps

Comment: Thank you for the update ! It is perfect ! You saved me a lot of time and stress, really appreciate it !

Comment: @Orohena if you intend to open only in Excel you could output to an XLSX file immediately with `df.to_excel('combined.xlsx', sheet_name='my_sheet_name_HERE')` where the `sheet_name` bit is optional.  It may be handy. :O)

Comment: it took me time to make it work (didn't install the appropriate package to make it work and didn't read properly the bug report... That's how far I'm starting from...) but now it does work ! And it is perfect, I have my 3 columns in my Excel file it's so good ! Thank you so much for your help (If you know matplotlib, there might be question for you soon :D but I'll try by myself as much as possible)